# Best ways to error handle HTTP requests (GET, PUT, DELETE, POST), while dealing with the 'legit' deviations' from 200, eg. 304, 201 etc

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rest

this code works for me:

```
const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/validLink')
    return response.data
}
```

however with one added line it doesn't:

```
const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/validLink')
        .then(r => console.log(r.status)) // added line
    return response.data
}
```

with the second one I got console error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response is undefined`

1. why is this so?
2. what are the best ways to error handle HTTP requests (`GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `POST` respectively), in terms of facing the 'legit deviations' from `200`, eg. `304`, `201` etc

Answer (score 1):

The first block of code works because axios executes requests immediately. The server gets a request even if the `.then()` is not called. When an HTTP error is gotten as a response from the server it can be handled with `.catch()`

```
const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/validLink')
        .then(r => console.log(r.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message)) 
}
```

If an HTTP error is gotten from the server as a response, the error message is logged to the console